# JavaScript: code optimization

Tags: javascript

Knowing that:

```
var STEP = {
    GET_CONF:                    1,
    CHOOSE_CREATE_CONTINUE_JOIN: 2,
    CHOOSE_CREATE:               3,
    CHOOSE_CREATE_VALIDATE:      4,
    CHOOSE_JOIN:                 5,
    CHOOSE_JOIN_VALIDATE:        6,
    WAITING_OTHER_PLAYERS:       7,
    POSITION_BOATS:              8,
    POSITION_BOATS_VALIDATE:     9,

    FIGHT_WAITING_FOR_ALL:      10,
    FIGHT_CHOOSING_A_TARGET:    11,
    FIGHT_WAITING_RESULTS:      12,

    GAME_OVER:                  13,
    ASK_RESTORE:                14
};
```

I want to make the following code:

```
this.update = function(board) {
    var bd=board.display;
    switch(board.step) {
        case STEP.CHOOSE_CREATE_CONTINUE_JOIN:
            bd.showChooseCreateContinueJoin(bd);
            break;
        case STEP.CHOOSE_CREATE:
            bd.showChooseCreate(bd);
            break;
        case STEP.CHOOSE_JOIN:
            bd.showChooseJoin(bd);
            break;
        case STEP.WAITING_OTHER_PLAYERS:
            bd.showWaitingOtherPlayers(bd);
            break;
        case STEP.POSITION_BOATS:
            bd.showBoardPositionBoats(bd);
            break;
        case STEP.FIGHT_WAITING_FOR_ALL:
            bd.showFightWaitingForAll(bd);
            break;
        case STEP.FIGHT_CHOOSING_A_TARGET:
            bd.showFightChoosingATarget(bd);
            break;
        /* ... */
        /* ... */
        /* ... */
        default:
            /* ? should never happen */
            fatal_error('Unknown step', new Array('Fatal error'));
    }
};
```

into a generic indexed table, something like:

```
this.update = function(board) {
    if (typeof fnDisplay[board.step] != 'undefined') {
        /* do something like board.display.fnDisplay(board.display) */
    }
};
```

How to do this?

Comment: Put that big thing in a function and assign it to `this.update`?

Comment: You mean you want to create an array of functions? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @PatrickHofman If you watch *carefully* the code, I want to make and array of functions, but if it was *that simple*, I wouldn't ask here. This is a bit more subtle than just an array of code, and people who have downvoted have read one word out of 10.

Comment: But what *is* your question then. 'How to do this?' isn't very specific.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I want to make and array of functions that are part of *another* object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
function getFunctions(bd){
    var fn = {}
    fn[STEP.CHOOSE_CREATE_CONTINUE_JOIN] = bd.showChooseCreateContinueJoin;
    fn[STEP.CHOOSE_CREATE]               = bd.showChooseCreate;
    fn[STEP.CHOOSE_JOIN]                 = bd.showChooseJoin;
    fn[STEP.WAITING_OTHER_PLAYERS]       = bd.showWaitingOtherPlayers;
    fn[STEP.POSITION_BOATS]              = bd.showBoardPositionBoats;
    fn[STEP.FIGHT_WAITING_FOR_ALL]       = bd.showFightWaitingForAll;
    fn[STEP.FIGHT_CHOOSING_A_TARGET]     = bd.showFightChoosingATarget;
    return fn;
}
```

Then:

```
this.update = function(board) {
    var bd=board.display;
    getFunctions(bd)[board.step](bd);
};
```

Or, just to be safe, check if the function exists and add your fallback:

```
this.update = function(board) {
    var bd=board.display;
    if(getFunctions(bd).hasOwnProperty(board.step)){
        getFunctions(bd)[board.step](bd);
    } else {
        /* ? should never happen */
        fatal_error('Unknown step', new Array('Fatal error'));
    }
};
```

Comment: I think your first block of code will give a syntax error, you may have to populate those functions using square bracket notation `[]`. Also, the `bd` variable is created from an argument to that method, so it may not be safe to use that when populating the map. Perhaps map the 'STEPS' to function names?

Comment: @Pudge601: Try for yourself: `var a = {'someString': function(){}}`. I did overlook the `bd` thing, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, but that's not what you're doing. You're doing `var a = {STEPS.SOMETHING: function(){} }`. It's the fact that you're trying to use a variable as the key, and that variable name contains a dot.

Comment: @Pudge601: I'm just storing function references in an array. The capitalized variables appear to be static strings (identifiers), and as such, can be used as keys. Function references can be used as variables. I fixed the `bd.` thing but building the result from a function with `bd` as parameter.

Comment: @Pudge601: oh, I see what you mean, yea, the dot notation's a problem... I'll figure something out.

Comment: Yeah, you can't use variables like that with that object notation. Simple enough to refactor to `var functions = {}; functions[STEP.SOMETHING] = function() {}`

Comment: Yeah, looks good, only other change I might make would be to do it as a map of function names like `steps[STEP.CHOOSE_JOIN] = 'showChooseJoin';`, and call using `bd[steps[board.step]].call(bd, bd);`. That way, you wouldn't have to call the function to repopulate the object every time `update` is called.